# how to import a class from the main app to the moudle? a

Tags: android

I have an app with a few modules. i tried to import a class from my main app to one of the modules using import + package name + class but android studio do not recognized the class or the package.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You'll need to provide more specifics about what you're trying to achieve, your environment, what steps you are taking, and exactly what result you get.

Comment: hi. i am using android studio 1.5.1. i have an app with few modules. i want to get a refrence from one of the modules to an object in the main app .but android studio do not recognized the class or the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that your module is a dependency of the main app, but the module itself doesn't depend on the main app code.  If it did you'd have a circular dependency which may or may not cause problems..

There are a few possibilities:

1. Move the code that your module needs into the module.  If your module is a dependency of the main app, your main app will still be able to reference  this code.
2. Similar to that, you could create a common interface in the module, and have your concrete class in the main app implement that interface.  The module could reference the interface, and you could modify your code so the module only knows about the interface class and does not know about the concrete class sitting in your main app code.

Comment: how can i overcome the circular dependency problem?

Comment: The best thing to do is refactor your code so that you don't have cyclic dependencies. Try to think in terms of the generality & specificity of the modules, and the major logical groupings. I.e. your app is specific, whereas your library module is general. So, move "general", non-app-specific code from your main app to your library.  In other words, move code that could potentially be shared across multiple apps into the library module. If you're still confused, try posting some code snippets that show what code the library is depending on.